# <h:form> not showing any output

Tags: jsf

I have a menu.xhtml with a form and a ui:repeat to create a navigation bar. But somehow it is not showing any data.

menu.xhtml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Kitchen Memories</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h4>Begin</h4>
        <h:form>
            <ui:repeat value="#{menuController.items}" var="item">
                <h:commandButton value="#{item.name}"
                                 action="#{menuController.setActive(item)}"
                                 style="margin-bottom: 5px;"
                                 immediate="true"
                                 styleClass="#{item.active == true ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-default'}"
                                 />
                <br/>
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:form>
        <h4>END</h4>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The `<h4>` Begin and End is visible. The rest not.

And my MenuController.java:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MenuController implements Serializable
{

    private List<Menu> items;


    public MenuController() 
    {
    }

    public void init()
    {
    items = new LinkedList<>();
    items.add(new Menu("Rezept finden", "findRecipe.xhtml", false));
    items.add(new Menu("Rezepte verwalten", "manageRecipe.xhtml", false));
    items.add(new Menu("Zutaten verwalten", "manageIngredient.xhtml", false));
    System.out.println("MenuController aufgerufen.");
    }

    public String setActive(Menu item)
    {
        System.out.println("Call: setActive");
        setAllInactive();
        item.setActive(true);
        return item.getUrl();
    }

    private void setAllInactive()
    {
        System.out.println("Call: setAllInactive()");
        for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
            items.get(i).setActive(false);
        }
    }

    public List<Menu> getItems() {
        System.out.println("Call getItems");
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Menu> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

And my Menu.java

```
public class Menu {

    private String name;
    private String url;
    private boolean active;

    public Menu(String name, String url, boolean active) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
        this.active = active;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Menu() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

When I clean and build the project I get a NullPointerException, but I don't understand from where and why I get that.

```
Information:   Session event listener threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener.getSessionContext(WeldTerminalListener.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener.sessionDestroyed(WeldTerminalListener.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:910)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:854)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:842)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:955)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:6164)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1172)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.unloadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.unloadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2394)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.stop(WebApplication.java:190)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.stop(EngineRef.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.stop(ModuleInfo.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.stop(ApplicationInfo.java:380)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.unload(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1059)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.undeploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1099)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.UndeployCommand.execute(UndeployCommand.java:412)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I really don't know why it isn't showing anything.

Comment: ok thank you for your advise, but i still can't see anything.... But when i CLean and Build it again, I get a NullPointerException... But i don't understand why and from where...

Comment: You can ignore that NPE during undeploy (just upgrade your IDE and sever to latest). As to your concrete problem of the page displaying nothing in browser, there are many possible causes for this. The way you put the question gives me the impression you already don't know basic HTML. To exclude one and other, please first tell if `FacesServlet` is successfully invoked or not. You can easily observe this in webbrowser by rightclick and *View Page Source*. Do you still see JSF tags like `<h:head>` and `<h:form>` in there? Or are they successfully rendered as HTML like `<head>` and `<form>`, etc?

Comment: yes i know basic HTML ;) honsetly, i don't know what went wrong, because after juswt running it again now it worked... It is being invoked and now shown correctly... Thats weird... I hope it won't happen again..